# Last array element keeps returning false

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have a time/date converter. When the user enters "130" for example it returns "06/07/2016 01:30:00" when they enter "6 7 16" for example it returns "06/07/2016 00:00:00" but when the user enters "6 7 16 130" for example it returns "06/07/2016 false:00" 
Here is my relevant code (can show more if need be):

```
function checkDateTime(val) { 
  var nowDate = new Date();

    var month, day, year, time;
    var ar;    
    if (eval(val)) {
      var tval = val.value;
      ar = tval.split(' ');
      if (ar.length === 3) {  // i.e. if it's supposed to be a date
    ar[0] = month;
    ar[1] = day;
    ar[2] = year;
    document.getElementById("FromDate").value = CheckDate(val) + ' ' + '00:00:00';
    //checkDate(ar[0] + ' ' + ar[1] + ' ' + ar[2]);
      }

    //alert(LeftPadZero(ar[0]) + ' ' + LeftPadZero(ar[1]) + ' ' + LeftPadZero(ar[2]));
    //alert(CheckDate(ar[0] + ' ' + ar[1] + ' ' + ar[2]));

      if (ar.length === 1) {  // if it's a time
    ar[0] = time;
    var MM = nowDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var DD = nowDate.getDate();
    var Y = nowDate.getFullYear();
    var  nowDateFormat = LeftPadZero(MM) + '/' + LeftPadZero(DD) + '/' + Y;
    alert(ar[0]); 
    document.getElementById("FromDate").value = nowDateFormat + ' ' + checktime(val) + ':00';
      }

    if (ar.length === 4) {  // if date and time

      ar[0] = month;
    //  alert(ar[0]);
      ar[1] = day;
    //  alert(ar[1]);
      ar[2] = year;
    //  alert(ar[2]);
      ar[3] = time;
    //  alert(ar[3]);

        document.getElementById("FromDate").value = CheckDate(val) + ' ' + checktime(val) + ':00';

     // alert(ar[0] + ' ' + ar[1] + ' ' + ar[2] + ' ' + ar[3]);
     }
    }
}

function CheckDate(theobj) {
    var isInvalid = 0;
    var themonth, theday, theyear;
    var arr;
    if (eval(theobj)) {
        var thevalue = theobj.value;
        arr = thevalue.split(" ");
        if (arr.length < 2) {
            arr = thevalue.split("/");
            if (arr.length < 2) {
                arr = thevalue.split("-");
                if (arr.length < 2) {
                    isInvalid = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isInvalid == 0) {
            themonth = arr[0];
            theday = arr[1];
            if (arr.length == 3) {
                theyear = arr[2];
            } else {
                theyear = new Date().getFullYear();
            }
            if (isNaN(themonth)) {
                themonth = themonth.toUpperCase();
                //month name abbreviation array
                var montharr = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
                for (i = 0; i < montharr.length; i++) {
                    //if the first 3 characters of month name matches
                    if (themonth.substring(0, 3) == montharr[i]) {
                        themonth = i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (themonth < 1 || themonth > 12) {
                    isInvalid = 1;
                }
            }
        }




        if (isNaN(themonth) || isNaN(theday) || isNaN(theyear)) {
            isInvalid = 1;
        }

        if (isInvalid == 0) {
            var thedate = LeftPadZero(themonth) + "/" + LeftPadZero(theday) + "/" + LeftPadZero(theyear);
            return thedate;
        } else {
            return false;
    }
    }
}

function checktime(x) {
     var tempchar = new String;
     tempchar = MakeNum(x);
     if (tempchar != '' && tempchar.length < 4) {
        //e.g., if they enter '030' make it '0030'
        if (tempchar.length == 3) {
           tempchar='0' + tempchar;
        }
        //e.g, if they enter '11' make it '1100'
        if (tempchar.length == 2) {
           tempchar=tempchar + '00';
        }
        //e.g, if they enter '6' make it '0600'
        if (tempchar.length == 1) {
           tempchar='0' + tempchar + '00';
        } 
      }
      if (tempchar==null || tempchar == '') {
        return false;
       }
       else {
          if (tempchar=='2400') {
             return false;
          }else{
             var tempnum= new Number(tempchar);
             var swmin = new Number(tempnum % 100);
             var swhour = new Number((tempnum-swmin)/100);
             if (swhour < 25 && swmin < 60) {
                x = LeftPadZero(swhour) + ":" + LeftPadZero(swmin);
        return x;
             }   
             else {
                return false;
             }
          }   
     }
return false;

/*
     if(eval(changecount)!=null){
        changecount+=1;
     }
*/
}

function MakeNum(x) {
     var tstring = new String(x.value);
     var tempchar = new String;
     var f = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < tstring.length; i++) {
          // walk through the string and remove all non-digits
         chr = tstring.charAt(i);
         if (isNaN(chr)) {
             f=f;
          } 
         else {
             tempchar += chr;
             f++;
          }
      }          
      return tempchar;
}
```

I have tried numerous things to figure out why the time element returns false in an array of length 4, but not an array length 1 for some reason, including setting various alerts and checking the console. I have googled this problem several times and came up empty.

To reiterate, my problem is that the time element returns false in an array of 4, and what I am trying to accomplish is for the user to input a date and time and have them both formatted and displayed correctly.

Can anybody help and/or offer any advice and/or suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: user enters '130' should convert to '06/07/2016(today's date) 01:30:00'
6 7 16 should convert to '06/07/2016 00:00:00'
6 7 16 130 should convert to '06/07/2016 01:30:00'

Comment: `eval()`? that's never a good sign...

Comment: He's just saying improperly using eval opens up your code for injection attacks, among other things.

Comment: Can you update your question with a list of acceptable input formats and what they should convert to? If you can't answer that question, the no one else here can help you accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some missing parts here... various functions and whatever input type these ones need are excluded from your post... However, taking a guess, I'm going to say that when you are making your final "checktime" call, rather than passing the full "val" variable, you should just be passing the last chunk of your split input, "ar[3]" in this case.  That way, only that piece is evaluated by the function.

IE:

```
document.getElementById("FromDate").value = CheckDate(val) + ' ' + checktime(val) + ':00';
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("FromDate").value = CheckDate(val) + ' ' + checktime(ar[3]) + ':00';
```

Again, this is just a guess due to the missing pieces.

Edit:
After getting some additional details, the issue DOES seem to be in the data being sent to the checktime function, however, due to the current code setup, the fix is actually just making sure that the data being processed by the checktime function is only the last item in the array... see below for the correction within the checktime function:

```
tempchar = MakeNum(x);
```

becomes

```
tempchar = MakeNum(x).split(' ').pop();
```

Comment: tried that. it threw the error "cannot read property 'value' of undefined" for this line:                                                                                                         var tstring = new String(x.value);                                                                   in the MakeNum(x) function. i tried to show only the relevant code but can show more if need be

Comment: So then what type of data is expected by these functions?  What is "x" expected to be?

Comment: that function was given to me. the checkDateTime function was the only one i made. i had assumed x was meant to be whatever variable the function was performed on

Comment: Alright, then what is checkDateTime expected to receive as "val"?

Comment: the user's input in the "FromDate" field

Comment: But what is the actual data type? Can you share the code which creates the "FromDate" field?

Comment: <input type="text" name="FromDate" id="FromDate" value=""     maxlength=10 size=12 autocomplete="off" onFocus="this.select();"     onblur="CheckDate(this); checktime(this); checkDateTime(this);">

Comment: that worked with document.getElementById("FromDate").value = CheckDate(val) + ' ' + checktime(val) + ':00'; but now the year returns always as 2016. either way this was my biggest issue so thanks! i appreciate it

Comment: Glad to be of help! If my answer pointed you in the right direction, feel free to give it an upvote or mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: i did both. one last thing i thought i fixed the year but it only appears as the last 2 digits if the array length is 3 or 4